# Как повернуть изображение,не влияя на общий угол графики в PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, gdi

В pictureBox'e есть несколько разных изображений. Одно из этих изображений должно поворачиваться в сторону координат клика мыши и следовать к ним. Поворачиваю изображение так:

```
 Matrix.RotateAt(Angle,Position);
Graphics.Transform = Matrix;
Graphics.DrawImage(Image_2,Position);
```

Проблема в том,что изображение не перемещается точно на положение мыши,а в точку отклоненную на Angle градусов. Можно повернуть изображение другим каким-то способом,не влияя на угол самой графики?

Comment: Сперва переместить центр координат в центр изображения: TranslateTransform или соответствующее матричное преобразовение. Затем повернуть. Затем вернуть все как было.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Но ведь после очищения экрана и при новой отрисовке будет неправильно отображаться... Или есть способ плавно перемещать картинку без обновления экрана и прорисовки в новых координатах?

Comment: "без обновления экрана и прорисовки в новых координатах" как вы себе это представляете? Вся анимация строится отрисовке очередного кадра на котором что-то рисуется в новых координатах. Если вам нужна независимость рисуемых объектов - выносите в модельные классы, меняйте их состояние и рисуйте кадр целиком с учетом состояния моделей объектов. Никакого "волшебного" средства обойтись без написания кода в GDI нет.

Comment: @rdorn А в чем суть вашего комментария? Весь вопрос и заключался в том,как вынести в модельный класс и получить независимость,а потом прорисовать... А под "волшебным" средством я подразумевал что-то вроде CopyFromScreen

Comment: Суть в том, что "Весь вопрос и заключался в том,как вынести в модельный класс и получить независимость,а потом прорисовать." этого нет в вопросе. На вопрос который есть в тексте - Alexandr Petrov ответил более чем полностью. GDI не располагает высокоуровневыми средствами полноценных графических движков - он предоставляет только самые базовые элементы рисования плоской графики. Копировать с экрана конечно можно, но чем это вам поможет в контексте заданого вопроса для меня загадка.